# Why is the sizeof() this struct 8?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

```
struct t{  
    char days[20];  
    int date;  
    char x;  
    struct t *next;  
}*head  

printf("%ld\n", sizeof(head));
```

where `sizeof(*void)=8`, `sizeof(int)=4`, `sizeof(char)=1`

Why does it print 8?

Comment: because its a pointer?

Comment: Because you have forgotten the asterisk. `sizeof(*head)` will get you what you are looking for. Voting to close (typo).

Answer (score 5):

`head` is a pointer to the struct `t`, which is 8 bytes since I'm assuming you're running an x64 program.  If you want the size of the underlying type, do this:

```
sizeof(*head)
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `head` is a *pointer* to the struct rather than an actual instance of the struct. This means that `sizeof(head)` is the size of the pointer, which on your system happens to be 8 (notice that `sizeof(void*)` is also 8).

Hope this helps!

Comment: so it's not actually adding up the sizes of the elements in the struct. ok thanks

Comment: @user2821523 That's exactly right - it's just asking how much space the pointer is taking up.